# Data Augmentation for Regression ANN with low Sample Size

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-augmentation

There is a Dataset of 65 tuples. 
I want to Augment new Data from this set and validate my ANN on the original Data.
Is there a possibility, that my ANN already overfits on the augmentet Data. For example that the augmentation Is simulated by the ANN, and how does one prevent this ?

Comment: In theory it's possible, everything depends on your data, the model you're training and how you're going to augment your training data.

Comment: you were right. it learned the augmentation instead of the Data. I solved the problem by splitting the Dataset before augmentation and augment only a test set, and validate on data , never seen by the system.

Comment: I'll post it as the answer then if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it's possible, everything depends on your data, the model you're training and how you're going to augment your training data.